# New C++ API Documentation for OpenCV

Tags: python, c++, opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,I have 3 questions:

1. Is it possible to use the old API C++ for OpenCV while writing code in ROS?
2. If is not, does anybody know where can I find good documentation for the new OpenCV C++ API? some books I have read only have a tiny percent explaining this new API.
3. It should be better if I write the code on Python, how complete are the functions in Python comparing to C++ in writing code for ROS?

I'm more interested in the two first questions cause I have more experience writing code in C.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34951/new-c++-api-documentation-for-opencv/) by [DavidLavy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2177/davidlavy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2012-05-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Yes. There is even a package, [cv_bridge](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge) that converts between `sensor_msgs/Image` and `cv::Mat`.
2. The auto-generated [API documentation](http://docs.opencv.org) is quite excellent for the C++ API. In general, I think the C++ API has less of a learning curve than the C API.
3. Most (if not all) of the C++ functions are wrapped. However, I ran into quite a few functions In OpenCV 2.2 and 2.3 that were completely broken. It's possible that things have improved in OpenCV 2.4.

---

Originally posted by [mkoval](https://answers.ros.org/users/309/mkoval/) with karma: 524 on 2012-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
You can always use the old APIs. If you want to learn the new C++ one which is easier then look into these [documentations](http://docs.opencv.org/)

Hope it helps,
Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2012-05-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DavidLavy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2177/davidlavy/) on 2012-05-26**:
Thanks, what should I add to use the old API though?, the examples I have seen were using the new one.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-05-26**:
Old (iplimage) are the basics structure used in opencv even now. new Mat structures are the wrappers build on top of the old. So you can directly use them as such.